# Username and UserType Validation in asp.net using mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net, phpmyadmin

I have two tables in the database:

Login (LID,UName,UPasword,UserType_ID)

```
UserType(UserType_ID,UserType)
```

I need to validate username and usertype and create a session variable for UserName(UName).

Below is the code which I try but it shows me error

```
Error   58  The type or namespace name 'UserInformation' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

CODE

```
public string LogOn(UserInformation objLogOnUserInformation)
        {
           // ConnectionManager conCm = new ConnectionManager();
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection con = conn.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd, cmdOne;
                MySqlDataReader dr;
               // SqlDataReader dr;
                string _str = "U";
                cmd = new MySqlCommand("select LID  from Credentials", con);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    //checking user name is present in database
                    if (dr.GetValue(0).ToString() == objLogOnUserInformation.UserId)
                    {
                        dr.Close();
                        //retriving Password for the existing user
                        cmd = new MySqlCommand("select Pasword  from login where LID='" + objLogOnUserInformation.UserId + "'", con);
                        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            //checking the password is matching with the database
                            if (dr.GetValue(0).ToString() == objLogOnUserInformation.Password)
                            {
                                dr.Close();
                                cmd = new MySqlCommand("select UserType_ID  from login where LID='" + objLogOnUserInformation.UserId + "'", con);
                                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                                while (dr.Read())
                                {
                                    //checking user type 
                                    if (dr.GetValue(0).ToString() == _str)
                                    {
                                        dr.Close();
                                        cmdOne = new MySqlCommand("select UName from login where LID='" + objLogOnUserInformation.UserId + "'", con);
                                        dr = cmdOne.ExecuteReader();
                                        dr.Read();
                                        objLogOnUserInformation.SessionUserName = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                                        dr.Close();
                                        //if usertype is customer, U is returned
                                        Response.Redirect("gallery.aspx");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        dr.Close();
                                        cmdOne = new MySqlCommand("select UName from login where LID='" + objLogOnUserInformation.UserId + "'", con);
                                        dr = cmdOne.ExecuteReader();
                                        dr.Read();
                                        objLogOnUserInformation.SessionUserName = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                                        dr.Close();
                                        //If usertype is Admin, A is returned
                                        Response.Redirect("Reports.aspx");

                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                return " Either User Name or Password is not Valid";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: If `UserInformation` type is defined in a separate assembly then include a reference to that assembly in your main project.

Comment: User Information Reference is not available in assembly

Comment: Then check it's protection level (OR) spelling mistake.